# Crossing symmetry for descendant fields

Tags: conformal-field-theory

I know about the crossing symmetry in conformal field theory, which is a symmetry satisfied by the primary fields' conformal block. Is there a generalized crossing symmetry relation which holds also for conformal blocks of descendant fields?

Answer (score 1):

This can be derived by the idea of OPE. Consider the following correlator: $$< {\phi _1}|{\phi _2}({z_1}){\phi _3}({z_2})|{\phi _4} > $$
Insert a complete set of basis,  it can be written as : $$\sum_i<\phi_1|\phi_2(z_1)|\phi_i><\phi_i|\phi_3(z_2)|\phi_4>$$
Then we consider the limit $z_1\rightarrow z_2$. In this limit we can first do a OPE of $\phi_2$ and $\phi_3$, and it's easy to see that:$$\phi_2(z_1)\phi_3(z_2)\sim\sum_k<\phi_k|\phi_2(z_1-z_2)|\phi_3>\phi_k(z_2)$$
Therefore, we get another expression for the original correlator:
$$\sum_k<\phi_1|\phi_k(z_2)|\phi_4><\phi_k|\phi_2(z_1-z_2)|\phi_3>$$

Finally we analytically continue the expression to outside the region of $z_1\rightarrow z_2$. This completes the proof of crossing symmetry relation for any fields from $\phi_1$ to $\phi_4$.
$$\sum_i<\phi_1|\phi_2(z_1)|\phi_i><\phi_i|\phi_3(z_2)|\phi_4>=\sum_k<\phi_1|\phi_k(z_2)|\phi_4><\phi_k|\phi_2(z_1-z_2)|\phi_3>$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, conformal blocks of descendent fields obey the same crossing symmetry relations as conformal blocks of the corresponding primary fields.

For example, in a case where a descendent's blocks are obtained by acting on a primary's blocks with a differential operator, you can apply that operator to the crossing symmetry relation involving the primary's blocks, and get the crossing symmetry relation for the descendent's blocks.